# How to encode table based data in Vega-Lite?

Tags: encoding, data-visualization, vega, vega-lite

First of all, it is hard to describe what I exactly mean by "table based data", because in some way all the input data for vega is "table-ish", but this example should make it clear:

Most (if not all) of the Vega-Lite [examples](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/examples/vega-lite/line_color) for multi line charts use data like,

```
"data": {
  "values": [
    {"id": 0, "symbol": "A", "value": 4},
    {"id": 1, "symbol": "A", "value": 2},
    {"id": 0, "symbol": "B", "value": 3},
    {"id": 1, "symbol": "B", "value": 8}
  ]
}
```

which is simple to color the lines of `A` and `B` with an ecoding like this,

```
"mark": "line",
"encoding": {
  "x": {"field": "id", "type": "quantitative"},
  "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
  "color": {"field": "symbol", "type": "nominal"}
}
```

But what if I want to produce the same result with a table based form of data like this,

```
"data": {
  "values": [
    {"id": 0, "A": 4, "B": 3},
    {"id": 1, "A": 2, "B": 8}
  ]
}
```

**1. How can I encode table based data into one colored multi line chart?**

A basic encoding could be to create line charts for every field and layer them on top of each other like [this](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAkDODGALApgWwIaQFxUQFzwAdYsB6UgN2QHN0A6agSz0QFcAjOxge1IRQyUa6ALQAbZskoBmOgCtY3AHaQANOCgATdHkw5QECJAroxrZLGxgA2hsNhgkRpqsAGVVACCVgCwfIAEJW0gC+6vYQjs5WAIz+3jgATP5BOAAcIXZgALoaYRqQyErw3JqMStRWBhGQAB5VkABmjMhiLjhOLv54AJ6EyFaQAI6s6Ep4zDqMVJCZEPlGYug9yABOVrb21faQGKsA1oMSSgPhNUUlZRVVWTs9Dc2t7V5qUL39gyNjE7oTM3MRAHzM6RW5QPaHDrHU5gwrFUrlSr6MFGe76JotNqDILdPoDDpfcaTP4DIGGMkA3IQECZIA),

```
"encoding": {
      "x": {"field": "id", "type": "quantitative"}
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "A", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    },
    {
      "mark": "line",
      "encoding": {
        "y": {"field": "B", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }
  ]
```

But with this I don't know how to color the lines differently or how to create a legend.

**2. Is this type of input data idiomatic to the way vega/vega-lite is designed?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data that vega-lite works with is often known as "long-form" or "column-oriented" data. The type of data you're asking about is often known as "wide-form" or "row-oriented" data. This is discussed briefly in the documentation for Altair, a Python wrapper for vega-lite: https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data

In the current release of Vega-Lite (v2.X) your only option is to modify the data source to be column-oriented with an external tool. This will change in the v3.0 release of Vega-Lite, which adds the [Fold transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/fold.html) which is designed to convert row-oriented data to column-oriented within a chart specification.

So, in Vega-Lite 3, you could use the fold transform like this ([vega editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zEgN1gGwK4FMBnFMAbXQEtoSAGAGigEESAWByAIRIGYBfBytVQBGds1QAmdl1QAOXgF1+4KPABOsAHaEAZgHs1AWxLlI+7ELKRm0yEoV0VkQ7DUBrEpGwVN+SI4hIfE0AYz1oHwBzElAIQIAPGLMKfAtPKn9VAE8ABz9USABHXC14CkQyjD9lOKgspJ0UtIKsPD92eFz8qGLS8oQKKsgauMgw7AMGpstIN3x6jq7PTT1DHxxhlV4QXiA)):

```
{
  "data": {"values": [{"id": 0, "A": 4, "B": 3}, {"id": 1, "A": 2, "B": 8}]},
  "transform": [{"fold": ["A", "B"]}],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "x": {"field": "id", "type": "quantitative"},
    "y": {"field": "value", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "key", "type": "nominal"}
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! The clarification on the data forms is also very helpfull. I had a picture from [database forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_and_narrow_data) in my head, but couldn't remember the right terms.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution (a bit tedious) is to use layer and create n layers for n columns

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v3.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv", "format": {"type": "csv"}},
  "layer": [{
    "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "orange"},
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"timeUnit": "yearmonthdate", "field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
      "y": {"field": "temp_max", "type": "quantitative"}
    }
  }, {
    "mark": {"type": "line", "color": "red"},
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"timeUnit": "yearmonthdate", "field": "date", "type": "temporal"},
      "y": {"field": "temp_min", "type": "quantitative"}
    }
  }]
}
```

[image]

Future support for layer repeat (https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1274) may make this a more reasonable solution.